# returned array is undefined, not async

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For some reason my function is returning undefined while seemingly working in itself.

```
function getDomains() {
    $.ajax({
        url:    '/rewrites/cgi-bin/ajax.pl?action=listdomains',
        dataType:'json',
        async:  false,
        success: function( data ) {
            if (data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
            }
            else {
                alert(data.domains);
                return(data.domains);
            }
       }
   });
}

alert(getDomains());
```

My first alert shows a populated list but the second is undefined.  Does this make any sense?

Comment: Even though it is synchronous, you still can't return from a callback.

Comment: Your `return` statement is for the `success` callback - you're not returning anything from `getDomains`. You could put `var domains;` at the top of your function. Then, in your callback, use `domains = data.domains;`, and then put `return domains;` at the end of your function

Comment: @Alnitak how do you spell it: SJAX?

Comment: Read this for more information:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @nene great post, OP should read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a function for the success call.  That's why you're not getting a result from your getDomains function.  Assign it to a variable and return the variable after the ajax call.

```
function getDomains() {
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url:    '/rewrites/cgi-bin/ajax.pl?action=listdomains',
        dataType:'json',
        async:  false,
        success: function( data ) {
            if (data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
            }
            else {
                alert(data.domains);
                results = data.domains;
            }
       }
   });
   return results;
}

alert(getDomains());
```

Comment: Did you know you're alerting the results twice?

Comment: I simply took his code and showed him how to assign the results and return the domains from his function.  There was nothing in the question about removing multiple alerts.  I left that there to affirm that the getDomains() function actually returned an array and wasn't undefined as he previously stated.

Comment: I coded the alerting twice so I could compare data at the different points in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this, assuming you need your return for a function called `whateverFunc()`:

```
function getDomains() {
    $.ajax({
        url:    '/rewrites/cgi-bin/ajax.pl?action=listdomains',
        dataType:'json',
        async:  false,
        success: function( data ) {
            if (data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
            }
            else {
                whateverFunc(data.domains);
            }
       }
   });
}


function whateverFunc(domains){
    alert(domains);
}
```

You can't return anything from `success` callback, it makes no sense.
I would like also to complain about the `async:false` here. Why do you need it absolutely?
You should let the call be async and manage the blocked state by yourself with some mutex or something around. In fact, you should trigger popup or whatever you need to do after you get the answer in the `whateverFunc()`.
It's clean and you keep control on the blocking state.

Comment: This way, no need to set async false

Comment: This is a function that happens early on and is a blocker for any other functionality.  It is the only non async piece of nastiness.

Comment: @user2245703 Ha, ok, blocking UI is expected behaviour, makes more sense

Comment: yeah I really hate sync $.ajax calls but at least it's cleaner this way :(